# JustifiedCombobox, a subclassed combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, layout

In an attempt to answer [How to justify the characters in the drop-down list of a Combobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48172185/7032856) I've come up with this code.

`JustifiedCombobox` justifies the pop-down list's items *almost precisely after* pop-down list's been first created & customized and then displayed. After the pop-down list's been created, setting `self.justify` value to a valid one will again, customize the justification almost right after the pop-down list's first been *displayed*:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
    from tkinter import ttk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk


class JustifiedCombobox(ttk.Combobox):
    """
    Creates a ttk.Combobox widget with its drop-down list items
    justified with self.justify as late as possible.
    """

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Combobox.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.justify = 'center'


    def _justify_popdown_list_text(self):
        self._initial_bindtags = self.bindtags()
        _bindtags = list(self._initial_bindtags)
        _index_of_class_tag = _bindtags.index(self.winfo_class())
        # This dummy tag needs to be unique per object, and also needs
        # to be not equal to str(object)
        self._dummy_tag = '_' + str(self)
        _bindtags.insert(_index_of_class_tag + 1, self._dummy_tag)
        self.bindtags(tuple(_bindtags))
        _events_that_produce_popdown = tuple([  '<KeyPress-Down>',
                                                '<ButtonPress-1>',
                                                '<Shift-ButtonPress-1>',
                                                '<Double-ButtonPress-1>',
                                                '<Triple-ButtonPress-1>',
                                                ])
        for _event_name in _events_that_produce_popdown:
            self.bind_class(self._dummy_tag, _event_name,
                                                self._initial_event_handle)


    def _initial_event_handle(self, event):
        _instate = str(self['state'])
        if _instate != 'disabled':
            if event.keysym == 'Down':
                self._justify()
            else:
                _ = self.tk.eval('{} identify element {} {}'.format(self,
                                                            event.x, event.y))
                __ = self.tk.eval('string match *textarea {}'.format(_))
                _is_click_in_entry = bool(int(__))
                if (_instate == 'readonly') or (not _is_click_in_entry):
                    self._justify()


    def _justify(self):
        self.tk.eval('{}.popdown.f.l configure -justify {}'.format(self,
                                                                self.justify))
        self.bindtags(self._initial_bindtags)


    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self.__dict__[name] = value
        if name == 'justify':
            self._justify_popdown_list_text()


def select_handle():
    global a
    _selected = a['values'][a.current()]
    if _selected in ("left", "center", "right"):
        a.justify = _selected


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    for s in ('normal', 'readonly', 'disabled'):
        JustifiedCombobox(root, state=s, values=[1, 2, 3]).grid()
    a = JustifiedCombobox(root, values=["Justify me!", "left", "center", "right"])
    a.current(0)
    a.grid()
    a.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event: select_handle())
    root.mainloop()
```

**Review Concern(s):**

- My main concern is to code in an easy to read, efficient, and well-structured manner while still learning the language and concepts in computer science<sup>1</sup> such as OOP. Feel free to mention the tiniest issue or improvement that comes to your mind, as I am a beginner and I probably need it.
- I believe the code should run on both `python 3.x` and `python 2.7`, but I have only tested it for `python 3.6.3`. If the code doesn't work for those other versions, or it can work cross-version like I intended it to be but still could use improvements, please let me know.

---

<sup>1</sup>I haven't a degree in computer science or a very closely related subject.